# How to call in specific columns from .CSV

Tags: python, csv, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am calling in a .csv file that has a combination of text and numeric values in it that are all sorted by values that looks like this:

[image: screenshot of .csv for clarity]

When I try to call in the data, python gives me the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float: '7/24/15 0:10'`

Is there a way I can call in this csv and omit specific columns? So since I am getting an error for column 1 (date), can I call in the data but omit columns 1, 6 (weekday), 7 (date_UTC)? Similarly, how can I then omit any other columns that might have values that don't work in an array of floats?

Here's my code so far:

```
SummerCLfile = 'user/summer_clusters.csv'
Summer_CLdata = list( csv.reader( open( SummerCLfile ) ) )
Summer_CLheaders = np.array( Summer_CLdata[ 0 ] [ : ], dtype = 'str' )
Summer_CLalldata = np.array( Summer_CLdata[ 1: ], dtype = 'float32' )
```

These data are then called by type (i.e. call in 'X' and it gives me all the values for X at the given time).

I can always go into the data and delete the columns that I don't want but my life will be a lot easier later if I can call in the data that can't be turned into a float32

Comment: Please, post your data in a text format to help the reproducibility of the problem.

Comment: The numpy csv readers, `loadtxt` and `genfromtxt` let you specify `usecols`.